# Conditional Gaussians in Infinite Dimensions

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process, conditional-expectation, conditional-random-field

The law of the conditional Gaussian distribution (the mean and covariance) are frequently mentioned to extend to the separable Hilbert spaced valued case, i.e., for $(X,Y)$,
$$
\mu_{X|Y=y} = \mu_X - C_{XY}C_{Y}^{-1}(\mu_Y - y)
$$
and
$$
C_{X|Y=y} = C_{X} - C_{YX}C_Y^{-1}C_{XY}
$$

I was trying to trace a proof for this in the separable Hilbert space case, and all the papers I found tended to point to *Linear Estimators and Measurable Linear Transformations on a Hilbert Space* by A. Mandelbaum (1984).  Digging through that paper, there's one a part of the proof I'm stumbling on:
[image]

I'm struggling with that first equality in (3.6), where the conditional expectation becomes the summation.  Thanks for any help.  Alternatively, if someone has a reference to another (better?) proof, let me know.